# What is a good text for a tooltip to explain a tour's intensity on a website?

Tags: copywriting, text, tooltips

I'm working in a website that will sells tours. Each tour has a physical intensity. We have a slider bar that represents that intensity. It goes from green - yellow - red. The current text that appear when you mouse hover a ? icon says "Green represents a laid back tour, red active and between is a perfect blend of both." How can I improve the above text?

Comment: Can these activity level's be quantified in any way? Heart rate? Not suitable for children under 12? Or qualified … "like a walk in the woods" "like a sprint through a battlefield"?

Answer (score 6):

**Go green for chilled, red for thrilled. In-between is less extreme.**

Obviously the intent here is to make it short, snappy and catchy via the two rhymes. That second slightly cheesy almost-but-not-quite rhyme could be endearing in a way.

This makes it more memorable not just in the context of meaning of the slider, but perhaps also after leaving the site.

As always - try it out with some people and see what they think.

Comment: I think the terms depend on the conversational tone that the site has. If its a fun site full of quips and whatnots, then "chilled" and "thrilled" are fun words that fit in. But if the site has a serious, directive tone, then those labels don't fit.  And the tone that you should have depends on your target audience and what you're selling them. -- So whats the tone of your site?

Comment: We are selling tailor-made tours, not packages. We target wealthy people after 30 years old.

Answer (score 2):

While simplistic; would *Activity level* or *Physical activity level* not suffice?

The colors will become self explanatory at that point and the amount of mental processing by the user is minimal. It is certainly mundane in its approach; however my guess would be that the use of the slider would be conveyed both accurately and quickly.